# put childs above header in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to put childs in expandableListView at the top of the header, so that when user clicks on an item, the children show up above it and not below it.

any idea how it is possible?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this class:

[platform_frameworks_base/ExpandableListConnector.java at master · android/platform_frameworks_base](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ExpandableListConnector.java)

This is a package-private class, so you can't use it directly, but you can examine it to see how it works.

Turns out that `ExpandableListView` is really a `ListView` where the adapter has been wrapped in a way that "flattens" the groups and children into a single one-dimensional list. `ExpandableListConnector` is the class that maps the groups and children to their flattened positions.

You can do this same thing too, by using a straight `ListView` with a custom adapter.  In your case when you flatten the list, instead of positioning your child views *below* the group view, put the child views *above* the group view.

So `BaseExpandableListAdapter` orders like this:

```
    group1       0
       child1    1
       child2    2
```

You create your adapter to order like this:

```
       child1    0
       child2    1
    group1       2
```

Also, when the user expands and collapses a group, you need to update your adapter state to add/remove children to the list and recalculate all the flattened positions.

Answer (score 0):

That won't be possible by using ExpandableListView class of Android. You will have to create a custom class that will do this.